# Listing child pages depending on user capability (role)

Tags: user-roles, navigation, wp-list-pages

I need to list within a sidebar menu all child pages from the current parent page. The children pages are restricted for viewing by user roles, let's say "A" and "B" for now. I use the "[Members Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/)" to manage that.

I've created a function that works pretty well for listing these child pages but I can't find the way to NOT LIST the child pages which the current user has no access to.

So if i'm logged in as user with role "A", I can not see the child pages which role "B" has access, and vice versa.

Here's the [current code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/26c44f9e474350c12864834452faa710).

Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Thank you !

Comment: when you say restricting for viewing that is where? in the page summary?

Comment: @DavidLee I use the "Members Plugin". It add post meta to pages, which I can retrieve that way.  

`$page_role = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_members_access_role');
$user_role = sb_get_user_role();`

I need to match the children page's role with the user. I'm stuck there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Rol` is in the meta you have to get the IDs of all of them then compare the meta access rol to the rol of the user:

```
    $post_parent_ID = $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID;

    $title = $post->post_parent ? get_the_title( $post->post_parent ) : get_the_title( $post->ID );
    //we use get posts to get all posts for the given ID
    $children_pages_array = get_posts(array('numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'any', 'post_parent' => $post_parent_ID, 'suppress_filters' => false));
    //we get the user rol
    $user_role = sb_get_user_role();
    //here we create an array that will be populated with IDs
    $ID_pages_rol_array = array();
    foreach ($children_pages_array as $child_page_obj) {
        //we get the rol that can access this page
        $page_role = get_post_meta($child_page_obj->ID, '_members_access_role');
        //do the current user rol have access to this page?
        if ($page_role == $user_role) {
            //yes it does add to the IDs of pages that this rol can access
            array_push($ID_pages_rol_array, $child_page_obj->ID);
        }
    }
    $children = wp_list_pages(array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'include' => $ID_pages_rol_array, //lets send those IDs to be formatted as list items
        'echo' => 0,
        'depth' => 1
            ));
```

you can get the IDs with `get_posts` (actually the entire post object) after making the array of permitted IDs, that can be send to `wp_list_pages`.

Comment: Thank you so much David ! I needed to make one change by adding [0] to the $page_role variable to make this work.

`$page_role = get_post_meta($child_page_obj->ID, '_members_access_role')[0];` since the sb_get_user_role(); return a string instead of an array. It wasn't matching with the $page_role array.

Should we make this different or it's all good ? 

Again, thank you !!! You saved the day for tomorrow (Monday) I promised to provide a fix for that project. ;)

Comment: Ah I can see now, if a page grant access to user roles A & B, it won't list...

Comment: nice, i didnt know how the members plugin was doing the restriction so i put it like that, if what you have is an array, another `foreach` is needed to do the `IF` also a `in_array()`  check so you dont have duplicate pages.

Comment: Once finished tomorrow, I will publish the complete function for others to use.

Comment: The final working function with comments: [Here's the Gist !](https://gist.github.com/simonbouchard/a27335ebc25b99bdb916f53f73c51ac6)